# Image resizing in java

Tags: java, image-resizing

I have used the below code for resizing a image and storing it in a temp file

```
public File resizeImage(InputStream fileInputStream, String fileName, int newW,int newH) throws Exception {
        Graphics2D g = null;
        File file2= File.createTempFile("result",FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName));

        BufferedImage img = null;
        File tempFile1 = File.createTempFile("Temp1File",FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName)); // If not resizing send temp file1
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try{            
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile1);
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            outputStream = null;            
            img = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(tempFile1));
            int w = img.getWidth();  
            int h = img.getHeight();  
            BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, img.getType());  
            g = dimg.createGraphics();  
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);  
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newW, newH, 0, 0, w, h, null);
            ImageIO.write(dimg, FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName), file2);
        } catch(SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if(outputStream != null) 
                outputStream.close();
            if(fileInputStream != null) 
                fileInputStream.close();
            if(g != null)
                g.dispose();
            if(img != null) 
                img.flush();
        }
        return file2;
        }
```

When I am reading tempFile1 in the highlighted line I am getting exception 
**Socket Exception : Socket already closed.**
Can anyone help me with this

Comment: What is `tempFile1`?  Sounds like it's been covered to a URL reference and not a `File` reference?

Comment: Okay i was totaly misleaded by the title and the first sentence. The problem lies only in this piece of code? `new FileInputStream(tempFile1)` ?? If so please change the question to conform that. So everytime a comment arises which shows a question to the question refine the question to eliminate the confusion ;)

Comment: may be you have closed `tempFile1` resource before reading it.

Comment: It seems like only the first line is relevant in your code sample. So, please remove the remanining lines, but also show us where `tempFile1` is defined. In short, help us re-create this problem on our computers (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Here is my entire code. I am downloading image from amazon s3 and passing it here as InputStream.

Comment: It's very unlikely to get a SocketException during File-IO. I assume your Amazon `InputStream` is already closed. We can tell you more with the stack trace and the relevant code for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) for this purpose!